# Update and Delete query for merging records

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with following records

```
id | fname | lname | skills 

22 | Jane |  Doe | php,mysql 
43 | Jane |  Doe | java,oracle,php
45 | Jane |  Doe | mongo,mysql
```

id is primary key .I want to execute a query so that in the table looks like this

```
 id | fname | lname | skills 

45 | Jane |  Doe | php,mysql,java,oracle,mongo
```

skill will merged with latest id  and other duplicate records deleted

any help will be very useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE YourTable t
INNER JOIN(SELECT max(s.id) as max_id,s.fname,s.lname,GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(s.skills)) as skill_str
           FROM YourTable s
           GROUP BY s.fname,s.lname) t1
 ON (t.lname = t1.lname and t.fname = t1.fname AND t.id = t1.max_id)
SET t.skills = t1.skill_str
```

This will update the table to your desired concat, and then delete:

```
DELETE FROM YourTable t
WHERE t.ID NOT IN(SELECT MAX(s.id) FROM YourTable s
                  GROUP BY s.lname,s.fname)
```

The delete will work only if `ID` is unique! It will delete all records that are not the largest `ID`

**EDIT:** try this:

```
DELETE t
FROM candidate t
LEFT JOIN(SELECT MAX(s.candidate_id) as max_id FROM candidate s
          GROUP BY s.fname,s.lname) t1
 ON (t.candidate_id = t1.max_id)
WHERE t1.max_id is null
```

Comment: So where does he bring `YourTable` from ? :S

Comment: DELETE FROM candidate t WHERE t.candidate_id NOT IN(SELECT MAX(s.candidate_id) FROM candidate s
                  GROUP BY s.last_name,s.first_name)

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't WHERE t.candidate_id NOT IN(SELECT MAX(s.candidate_id) FROM candidate s ' at line 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113023/discussion-between-vipins-and-sagi).

Comment: This solution doesn't remove skill duplicates. "mysql" will be listed twice.

Comment: Your `DISTINCT` operates on skill lists, not on specific skills. 'php,mysql' isn't equal to 'mongo,mysql'. So it will be concatenated to 'php,mysql,mongo,mysql'.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
SELECT 
        MAX(id) AS id, fname, lname, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(skills)) AS skills
FROM
        < your_table >
GROUP BY
        fname, lname
```

References :

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: I want to update in table and delete other duplicate records completely from database.

Comment: yes, I just gave idea how to merge the skills, @sagi answer is your solution !

Comment: i am testing and varifying

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a limit of 10 skills per row you can normalize the `skills` column with the following query:

```
select distinct 
    s.fname, s.lname, 
    replace(
        substring(substring_index(s.skills, ',', p.pos),
        char_length(substring_index(s.skills, ',', p.pos -1)) + 1),
        ',', ''
    ) as skill
from
    skills s
cross join 
    (select 1 pos 
    union all select 2 
    union all select 3 
    union all select 4 
    union all select 5 
    union all select 6 
    union all select 7 
    union all select 8 
    union all select 9 
    union all select 10
) p on p.pos <= (char_length(s.skills) - char_length(replace(s.skills, ',', ''))) + 1
```

Result:

```
| fname | lname |  skill |
|-------|-------|--------|
|  Jane |   Doe |    php |
|  Jane |   Doe |   java |
|  Jane |   Doe |  mongo |
|  Jane |   Doe |  mysql |
|  Jane |   Doe | oracle |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0580ab5/2)

```
(char_length(s.skills) - char_length(replace(s.skills, ',', ''))) + 1
```

will return the number of skills (counting the commas).

```
    replace(
        substring(substring_index(s.skills, ',', p.pos),
        char_length(substring_index(s.skills, ',', p.pos -1)) + 1),
        ',', ''
    )
```

will extract a skill at a given position.

Instead of creating the positions table inline, you can use any existing table with an unbroken sequence of numbers.

To denormalize the result again, you can use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT skill)`:

```
select 
    s.fname, s.lname, 
    group_concat(distinct replace(
        substring(substring_index(s.skills, ',', p.pos),
        char_length(substring_index(s.skills, ',', p.pos -1)) + 1),
        ',', ''
    )) as skills
from skills s
cross join (
    select 1 pos 
    union all select 2 
    union all select 3 
    union all select 4 
    union all select 5 
    union all select 6 
    union all select 7 
    union all select 8 
    union all select 9 
    union all select 10
) p on p.pos <= (char_length(s.skills) - char_length(replace(s.skills, ',', ''))) + 1
group by s.fname, s.lname
```

Result:

```
| fname | lname |                      skills |
|-------|-------|-----------------------------|
|  Jane |   Doe | php,mysql,mongo,oracle,java |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0580ab5/3)

This way no skill appears twice in the list.